# OnClick not a function React JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Can somebody please Explain why this onClick doesn't work -- it says -- Expected `onClick` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `object` type.
at button
at div
at SignIn
at section
at div -- not entirely sure why this wouldnt be considered a function because how would the function be added to the call stack if not clicked?

```
const auth = firebase.auth();
// const fireStore = firebase.fireStore();
const App = () => {
    const [user] = useAuthState(auth);
// functions
const signInWithGoogle = () => {
    console.log("click");

    // const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    // auth.signInWithGoogle(provider);
};

console.log(user);
return (
    <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">here is my app</header>
        <section>
            {user ? <ChatRoom /> : <SignIn signInWithGoogle={signInWithGoogle} />}
        </section>
    </div>
);
};
export default App;
```

Sign in component

```
import React from "react";

const SignIn = (signInWithGoogle) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={signInWithGoogle}>Sign in with google</button>
        </div>
    );
};

export default SignIn;
```

Comment: Component properties are passed in as an object so destructure the prop you want: `const SignIn = ({ signInWithGoogle })...`

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a prop, it is passed into an object.
So, in order to access the function you should do `signInWithGoogle.signInWithGoogle`

A more elegant way could be to use object destructuring as follows:

```
const SignIn = ({signInWithGoogle}) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={signInWithGoogle}>Sign in with google</button>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the SignIn component.

All React component has a props argument.
Then signInWithGoogle function in i side the props object.

So the fix would be to destructure the props argument and adding brackets around “signInWithGoogle”

```
import React from "react";

const SignIn = ({ signInWithGoogle }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={signInWithGoogle}>Sign in with google</button>
        </div>
    );
};

export default SignIn;
```

Comment: wow okay that makes complete sense i like this solution thank you so much